# Trace information of clicking on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to write a html page where clicking on the hyperlink can be traced. That means I can get a statistic about how many people click on a hyperlink in my page, in a past period. If it is possible to know their ID, it would be better.

And I find this piece of code from the source of a web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function stc(e,linkIndex) {
  if (document.images) {
     var linkText;
     if (navigator.appName.toLowerCase()=="microsoft internet explorer") {
        linkText=e.innerText}
     else {
        linkText=e.textContent}
     if (linkText=="") {
        if (e.firstChild) {
           var firstChild=e.firstChild.nodeName.toUpperCase();
           if (firstChild=="IMG") {
              linkText="Image: "+getName(e.firstChild.getAttribute('src'))}}
        else {
           var nodeName=e.nodeName.toUpperCase();
           if (nodeName=="AREA") {
              linkText="ImageMap: "+e.href}}}
     if (linkText=="") {
        linkText=e.href}
     (new Image()).src="/a/i/stg.gif?f="+escape(document.location.href)+"&t="+escape(e.href)+"&i="+linkIndex+"&n="+escape(trimString(linkText))}}

function getName(s) {
  if (s.lastIndexOf('/')>=0) {
     return(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1,s.length))}
  else {
     return(s)}}

function trimString(s) {
  return(s.replace(/^\s*/,"").replace(/\s*$/,""))}
</script>
```

and I guess `<a href="http://www.google.com" onClick="stc(this, 1)">google</a>` will be able to track information of clinking on this link.

I don't know too much about `Javascript`, could anyone tell me, according to this code, where the tracing information is saved?

Comment: What do you mean by "trace"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

usually trace() in other languages is is just some kind of output and the best most simple way to do that in javascript is to call console.log("some output "). you can view the output in Google Chrome by right click on the page > inspect element, then click on the console tab, there you will see your output. in Firefox, you should get the Firebug add-on, there you can see the same output generated by console.log("some output") again within the console tab.

other browsers suck for dev so why even bother explaining?

Comment: Are you sure that will log the clinking on my page of others?

Answer (score 0):

You need serverside code to do this.

For example, you could have a gateway script that redirects users to the page they want to see:

```
http://www.example.com/portal/www.google.com/
```

From there, you can just save the user's request into a database and redirect the user to `www.google.com` almost instantly without the user really caring.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean... but I haven't found the "gateway script" in the link you gave, which redirects me to `http://www.iana.org/domains/example/`.

Comment: I'm using `example.com` as your example website. You need to read up on web development before doing something like this.